Low dimensional symmetric Euclidean immersions of the Klein quartic
I was wondering what the lowest Euclidean dimension the Klein quartic has a faithful symmetric immersion, that is an immersion such that all of its automorphisms* are distinct symmetries of the immersed surface.
Naturally there exists one in 23 dimensions since its automorphism group is a subgroup of $S_{24}$ which is isomorphic to the symmetry group of the 24-simplex. This can be seen as the regular map on the Klein quartic, $\{3,7\}_8$, has 24 vertices. All of its automorphisms correspond to permutations of its vertices and thus they are a subgroup of $S_{24}$. (There's also one in 55 dimensions courtesy of $\{7,3\}_8$ with 56 vertices, but I'm interested in low dimensional immersion.)
Since $\{3,7\}_8$ has 2 diagonal classes due to a theorem of McMullen & Schulte it has at most 2 pure symmetric realizations. Since it has no regular quotients[1] and thus no unfaithful symmetric realizations, there are either two faithful symmetric realizations of $\{3,7\}_8$ in lower dimensions adding to 23, or the 23-dimensional realization is the only one.
It is not difficult to show that every immersion of the Klein quartic induces an realization of $\{3,7\}_8$ of equal or lower dimension. So I would expect finding these low dimensional realizations of $\{3,7\}_8$ to be a little helpful. However I don't have any idea of where these realizations could be located.
Are any lower dimensional immersion of the Klein quartic known?

*Including orientation reversing automorphisms

The minimal dimensionalitynis likely less than $23$. By your argument icosahedral symmetry would be represented in $11$ dimensions using a $12$-simplex, but here an integer-point representation with that symmetry is rendered in only six dimensions.

@OscarLanzi Indeed, the icosahedron is represented in 11 dimensions, but as it has 3 diagonal classes additional representations are possible and as it turns out they exist. I believe as well that such exist for the {3,7}_8. Based on the representations of PSL(2,7) I imagine in 6D and 17D.

@OscarLanzi It has all the symmetry for PSL(2,7), but I need PGL(2,7), which means some semidirect product with the central inversion.  I have to check which ones give PGL(2,7) and have valid vertex stabilisers.
